# Send mail using python to required recipients

Tags: python, email, mime

I am trying to send email automatically from my official ID to another official ID. For that I have used following python script.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

fromaddr = "<SENDER MAIL ID>"
toaddr = "<RECIPIENT MAIL ID>"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT OF THE MAIL"

body = "Robot Uprising, We are coming for you"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "YOUR PASSWORD")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

While executing this I am facing issue as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailsendtest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
ImportError: No module named MIMEMultipart
```

I am a starter in python. Kindly provide inputs. Thanks !

Comment: It's `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart` in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

I find two problems with your `imports` assuming you're using Python3.

1. Change `from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart` to `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart`
2. Change `from email.MIMEText import MIMEText` to `from email.mime.text import MIMEText`

Also make sure you have the libraries installed if these don't work.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue and I am facing a new issue now.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailsendtest.py", line 15, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  File "C:\Integration\python\pyt\lib\smtplib.py", line 259, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Integration\python\pyt\lib\smtplib.py", line 319, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Integration\python\pyt\lib\smtplib.py", line 294, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: This has to do with the `smtp` library that you're using.